# How to get the last 12 months of Facebook page insights from their Graph API

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the last 12 months of page insights data like unique. I am getting an array with the fields on the returned results, but it seems they are only for that day, or maybe I am mistaken; the response also contains pagination; when I go on the previous link, it only returns. I may be missing something, but I'd appreciate it if anyone could assist or explain it to me. The following is the function that makes the API response.

```
public static function getMultipleMetrics($pageID, $pageAccessToken, $metric)
{
    $current = Carbon::now();

    $getURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $pageID . "/insights";

    $params = [
        "access_token" => $pageAccessToken,
        "metric" => $metric,
        "period"  => "days_28",
        "since" => $current->subMonths(12),
        "until" => $current
    ];

    $response = Http::get($getURL, $params);

    return $response;
}
```

**The response**

```
array:2 [▼
  "data" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "name" => "page_impressions"
      "period" => "days_28"
      "values" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "value" => 72
          "end_time" => "2022-04-04T07:00:00+0000"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "value" => 69
          "end_time" => "2022-04-05T07:00:00+0000"
        ]
      ]
      "title" => "28 Days Total Impressions"
      "description" => "28 Days: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content o ▶"
      "id" => "pageid/insights/page_impressions/days_28"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▶]
  ]
  "paging" => array:2 [▼
    "previous" => "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/pageid/insights?access_token="
    "next" => "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/pageid/insights?access_token=
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 90 days of insights can be viewed at one time when using the `since` and `until` parameters.please refer to [Meta page insight](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/insights)  limitation section